# Асинхронное подключение зависимостей в webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Делаю один nodejs модуль, который должен уметь подключаться в браузере. Почти все части хорошо портируются кроме одной. Один из дочерних модулей я не могу в браузере подключить синхронно. Как это всё выглядит:

**foo.js**

```
const bar = require('./bar')

bar.baz()
```

В модуле bar для браузера выполняется некая асинхронная операция, результатом которой является экспортируемый объект `bar`. Повторю, в ноде я могу это выполнить синхронно, с этим проблем нет.

**bar.js**

```
some_async_operation().then(bar => {
    // resolve bar here
})
```

Я знаю, что webpack умеет подгружать зависимости из других чанков перед выполнением основного. Допустим если `c.js` зависит от `a.js` и `b.js`, webpack подгрузит последние 2 и только потом выполнит `c.js`. Интересует именно эта возможность. Нужно, чтоб webpack выполнил `bar.js` и только потом произошёл resolve зависимости в `foo.js`.

**P.S.**

Я в курсе про `import()`, но не хочу рушить архитектуру и плодить лишние скопы.

Comment: [Async Loader](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#async-loader) - это не то, что требуется?

Comment: @etki насколько я понимаю, асинхронная операция должна быть в момент работы загрузчика. Из документации вот совсем не понятен этот момент. Есть примеры как интегрировать рантайм в async loader?

Comment: Я его не использовал, если честно, но async(require) должен без проблем преобразовываться в require(async)